# Whitespace before \cite that ends a sentence or a paragraph

Tags: spacing, citing

If I summarize content from another source, I'll use `\cite` to reference the author. In natural sciences it seems to be standard to use `\cite` at the end of the sentence or paragraph that containts cited content.

**Example**:

```
Lore ipsum \cite{OtherSource}.
```

Is there any recommended way about whitespacing before the `\cite` command? I could go with

```
Lore ipsum \cite{OtherSource}.
```

or

```
Lore ipsum\cite{OtherSource}.
```

**Edit:** My question is about, whether I should include a whitespace or not.

Comment: `Lorem ipsum~\cite{Source}`

Comment: @egreg: As far as I understand ~, it forces the creation of a whitespace. My question was about, if I should include a whitespace at all

Comment: Definitely add one. The tie will keep it with the preceding word; in case of author-year citations the tie can be pulled away in problematic cases.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For citation styles that typeset the content of `\cite` in the main text body (e.g., numeric, alphabetic and author-year styles) you definitely want a space before the citation, i.e.,

```
Lorem ipsum \cite{<key>}.
```

or (especially in case of numeric styles)

```
Lorem ipsum~\cite{<key>}.
```

For styles that move the citation content into a footnote (e.g., author-title and verbose styles), I recommend to use

```
Lorem ipsum.\cite{<key>}
```

Some European styles prefer the footnote mark before the punctuation, though (thanks to jon for the hint).

In case you use `biblatex` and its `\autocite` command, you may use

```
Lorem ipsum \autocite{<key>}.
```

independent from the actual style -- `\autocite` will move the footnote mark after the end-of-sentence period in case your style uses footnotes.

Comment: In the last case, some footnote-based (European) styles prefer the citation command to be inside the punctuation.

Comment: The 'magic moving' punctuation business is configurable in `biblatex`. For non-`biblatex` styles, the `cite` package can do 'magic moving' if requested, or my own `natmove` package provide the same concept for `natbib`-dependent bibliographies.